# ArmorDropChances Data Tag below 0.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Does the Minecraft binary recognize a value for `ArmorDropChances` below `0.1f`? I have enemies that are dropping armour and it is dropping way too often considering the drop chances are 0.001f (I know its about 1/1000) but it feels like every fifth enemy is dropping the item. Maybe I just have insane luck, but something isn't working here. (I don't think it matters what items are dropping just that the items are dropping seemingly too fast).

Here's the section of my command if you wanted to know the drop rates.

`ArmorDropChances:[0.004F,0.2F,0.001F,0.2F]`

EDIT: I think I know what's going on, the items that I have like a 20% drop rate on what is supposed to be a common drop. But after changing the drop rate of what is supposedly the helmet to 0.004 I found the common drop never dropped anymore and the armour was dropping just as much

Answer (score 1):

I have reason to believe the drop chances are automatically arranged not by slot position Ex. if the drop rates were 1, 0.5, 0.3, 1 it would mean the head drops equal 1, chest equal to 0.5, legs are 0.3, etc. Its **ACTUALLY** the order you have the gear arranged in your command. So if in the command has the feet's data tags, attributes, displays, ids, ect. before the rest of the armour than the drop chances will be 1=feet, 0.5=head, 0.3=chest, 1=legs. For example of course.

**TL:DR OR MAKES NO SENSE** in my case, 0.004 is affecting the common drop, 0.2 is affecting  one of the armour pieces, 0.001 is affecting the common drop and 0.2 is affecting the other armour.

Comment: This is not really correct. The game has no idea what constitutes different armor types as far as drop chances are concerned. If the leg armor was set to be a piece of dirt, there's no way the game would know that that's for the leggings. The index of `ArmorDropChances` corresponds to the index within `ArmorItems`. The order within `ArmorItems` is the same no matter what, being 0=feet, 1=legs, 2=chest, 3=head. Putting a helmet in slot 1 means they are wearing a helmet on their legs, **not** that slot 1 is now their head slot.

Comment: that's exactly what I summarized, or at least what I meant